# Firebase UI custom xib and class iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to figure out how to do both a custom xib and class for a `tableviewcell` using Firebase UI

Things I have setup in XCode:
I have a custom xib file called `EventCellView.xib` and
the custom tableviewcell inside of the xib has a reuse id of `eventCell`, it is also of the class `EventTableViewCell`

my code for the `EventTableViewCell` custom class is

```
class EventTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var eventTitle: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UILabel!

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
   super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() { super.awakeFromNib() }
}
```

Currently, reading the Firebase UI docs from github I've tried multiple different ways to setup my datasource, this is the one most recent one:

```
 self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref:fbRef, 
                               nibNamed: "EventCellView", 
                               cellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell", 
                               view: self.eventTable)


 self.dataSource!.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
    let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot
    var customCell = cell as! EventTableViewCell
    customCell.eventTitle.text = snap.key
  }
```

Basically per the instructions on Github it says to subclass `UITableViewCell` and to implement the init (style, resuseId) method, I then specify the `cellResuseIdentifier` and nib inside of the datasource and I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason:
```

> invalid nib registered for identifier (eventCell) 
>   - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance

Any help would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: Did you set your reuse identifier i.e. `eventCell` in your cell's xib file?

Comment: Yep, turns out it was because of a hidden label floating around outside of the table view cell....